# Vim: z+enter does not bring the current line to the top, instead it's moved 5 lines from top

Tags: vim

In VIM, normally, <kbd>z</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will scroll the current line the cursor is on to the top of the screen (call it line 0).  On RHEL8.4 <kbd>z</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> only brings the line close (to line 5) but not to the top.

Similarly, <kbd>z</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> will not scroll the current line to the bottom of the screen but 5 lines away.

The rest of VIM seems fine for going to lines and h-j-k-l'ing around.

Can someone suggest a place to start looking for more information about this "phenomenon"?

Answer (score 3):

You need to reset your `'scrolloff'` option:

```
:set scrolloff=0
```

I don't like how RHEL sets some defaults, and I always do `:scriptnames` to find the file they set up and move it out of the way.

Comment: FWIW, `set scrolloff=5` is set in `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim`.